# Android Bluetooth - Connection Refused Unless Previously Paired/Repaired (Need a Fix)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application that connects as a client to a Bluetooth SPP enabled device. My phone is an HTC Inpire 4G and I am using platform 2.3.3. At first I wasn't able to connect at all even using the new InsecureRfcomm socket connection.

```
/* Does not work, Service Discovery Exception when trying to connect */
MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
tmp = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( myUUID );
tmp.connect();
```

I was able to connect only if paired manually using Bluetooth settings with the following code. if the application is killed or phone shut down, I must manually unpair and pair again before connection is established again. I do not mind as much that I must pair before connecting, but I do mind that I must unpair and pair back again in order to establish a connection.

```
/* This is a workaround method to establish connection */
BluetoothDevice hxm = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mmDevice.getAddress());
Method m;
m = hxm.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(hxm, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Please, let me know if there is another workaround for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Strange you have to use reflection on createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() to establish connection. You mentioned you tried just doing normal createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() before? What exactly was the exception?

Comment: @broody He's not using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord via reflection but createRfcommSocket - as messed up as it sounds, I have the same issues trying to pair a bluetooth printer. Using the api it fails, but using the above mentioned reflection it at least pairs